# How to Remove SPDIF cable from Video Card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, spdif

This is probably a stupid question.. I'm trying to remove the 2-pin SPDIF cable connected to my video card and motherboard but it seems like the cables are too tight and the whole socket's coming off if I pull hard. Is there any trick to removing these?

Answer (score 4):

As long as this is no "snap-in" socket, there are some sockets that are only attached to the pins they surround via pressure. So if the plug is holding onto the socket more than the socket to the pins, it can happen that you pull it out together with the cable.

You can either risk pulling out the socket (you shouldn't destroy you motherboard here, because the pins are soldered onto it) and put it back on. Or you try to support the socket with the help of a small but blunt item (to not scratch your motherboard) while pulling out the cable.

I never had this problem with SPDIF, but with other similar small connectors.

And btw: there are no stupid questions ;)

Comment: good idea(s)!, the way things are soldered (by machine) today even being very carefull, some of the tiny stuff is falling off. Many small gadgets now they do not even bother to pin the socket through the pcb boards, and the quantity of solder must save them .005cents.